# How to get interior uniform lightning?

Tags: unity, lighting

I'm trying to reach uniform lighting as in this image.
This scene i've bought is rendered with 3ds and v-ray (i suppose).

[image]

This is the same scene i've imported in Unity.

I've put a "big" point light on top of my room, i've added also directional light and a Reflection Probe.

This is my (unsatisfactory) result:
[image]

This is my baking settings: 
[image]

Do you have some advice to improove my Unity lightining as the first scene ?

Thanks